# Uploading on a FTP server NodeJS : Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ftp

I am using https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp to upload a file on a FTP server. Here is my code:

```
    const Client = require('ftp');

    console.log('CONNECTING...')
    const c = new Client();
    c.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('READY');
        c.put('test.csv','test.remote-copy.csv',function (err) {
            if (err) { console.log('PUT err : ' + err); };
            c.end();
        });
    });
    // connect to ftp server
    c.connect({
        host: "my-adress",
        port: 22,
        user: "my-user",
        password: "my-pass",
        debug: console.log
    });
    console.log(c);
```

In the log of c, the config is well set but is says connected false, however I use exactly the same username/password on FileZilla and it works fine :

```
 options: 
{ host: 'my-address',
  port: 22,
  user: 'my-user',
  password: 'my-pass',
  secure: false,
  secureOptions: undefined,
  connTimeout: 10000,
  pasvTimeout: 10000,
  aliveTimeout: 10000 },
connected: false,
_events: { ready: [Function] },
_eventsCount: 1 }
```

Comment: The function connect() is not synchronous. Therefore if you log on the next line, you can’t expect c.connected to be true. What is the issue? The line with log “READY” is not being called?

Comment: Yea, the ready wasn't displayed in the console but I found my mistake , thanks a lot for helping however :)

Comment: What was your mistake? I'm using the same ftp package and getting the same error connected: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my mistake and feel idiot, it is just that I used a ftp package but my server was in SFTP. If you have the same problem use this package and it works perfectly : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client